# identify node followed by another node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to xslt. I have a xml like this,

```
<para>Randomized practice trains adaptability to different tasks, thereby facilitating the transfer to activities of daily life and improving patient’s reactions.<!-- [443] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_443" target="literature"/> Practicing in unpredictable situations promotes and facilitates the development of effective strategies. The neurologic patient needs success in rehabilitation because successfully executed movements cause strategies to be stored in the central nervous system (CNS).<!-- [369] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_369" target="literature"/> Success in executing movements increases motivation, which is also a requirement for mastering new tasks in the future. The therapist’s instructions should not be directed toward performing the movement but the goal or effect of the movement; the task should have an external focus. This would, in turn, lead to improved efficiency of movement, decreased frequency of errors, and greater maximum strength that the patient can generate.<!-- [448] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_448" target="literature"/> <!-- [444] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_444" target="literature"/> <!-- [445] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_445" target="literature"/> <!-- [117] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_117" target="literature"/> <!-- [264] --><link idref="b1781a677a290_264" target="literature"/> All these effects contribute to the movement becoming automatic.</para>
```

I need to add a ',' between  nodes if couple of  placed successively ( followed by another node).

so, for above example xml, output should be,

```
<para>Randomized practice trains adaptability to different tasks, thereby facilitating the transfer to activities of daily life and improving patient’s reactions.<!--[443]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_443" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">443</dummy></link> Practicing in unpredictable situations promotes and facilitates the development of effective strategies. The neurologic patient needs success in rehabilitation because successfully executed movements cause strategies to be stored in the central nervous system (CNS).<!--[369]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_369" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">369</dummy></link> Success in executing movements increases motivation, which is also a requirement for mastering new tasks in the future. The therapist’s instructions should not be directed toward performing the movement but the goal or effect of the movement; the task should have an external focus. This would, in turn, lead to improved efficiency of movement, decreased frequency of errors, and greater maximum strength that the patient can generate.<!--[448]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_448" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">448,</dummy></link> <!--[444]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_444" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">444,</dummy></link> <!--[445]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_445" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">445,</dummy></link> <!--[117]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_117" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">117,</dummy></link> <!--[264]--><link idref="b1781a677a290_264" target="literature"><dummy cstyle="Superscript">264</dummy></link> All these effects contribute to the movement becoming automatic.</para>
```

I tried to write a xsl template to identify successive  noted and added the ',' as follows,

```
<xsl:template match="link">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@target = 'literature'">
                <xsl:variable name="refCount"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(@idref, '_'))"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="empty(node())">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                            <xsl:element name="dummy">
                                <xsl:attribute name="cstyle">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="'Superscript'"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$refCount"/>
                                <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::link]">
                                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:element>                            
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>               
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:when> 
    </xsl:choose>
```

Any idea to correct this xpath?

Also, I tried to use `node()` method as shown below.

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::link]">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
</xsl:if>
```

While adding `node()`, comma',' is not reflecting in output.

It would be very helpful to add ',' between `<link>` tags.

Comment: What is the logic of not having a `comma` after value `369` in the output XML when you have mentioned that you require `comma` between the `<link>` tags.

Comment: These numbers are reference no. We are separating the reference number using 'comma'. Whenever multiple number is presenting then those should be separate using ',' (like 1, 2, 3..etc). If single number is present in superscript then there is no requirement of comma.

Comment: Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor can you use? Sounds like a good job for XSLT 2 or 3 and `for-each-group group-adjacent`.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add a comma if the first following sibling, that is not a comment or empty text node, is a `link` element....

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()
                 [not(self::comment() | self::text()[not(normalize-space())])]
                 [1][self::link]">
```

Try this XSLT (which I have simplified, by moving the test conditions into the template match

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="link[@target = 'literature'][empty(node())]">
        <xsl:variable name="refCount"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(@idref, '_'))"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <dummy cstyle="Superscript">
                <xsl:value-of select="$refCount"/>
                <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[not(self::comment() | self::text()[not(normalize-space())])][1][self::link]">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
                </xsl:if>
            </dummy>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response "Martin Honnen". It's working on only mentioned individual para. I couldn't merge on my original xslt where mentioned other conditions for all nodes. But, your code is guide use to write short-cut.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not "Martin Honnen". I think you made this comment against the wrong answer...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added only above mentioned <xsl:if> condition into my original xslt and it's working properly without any issue. Thank for your support guys.

Comment: Oh..:)..I am a new member to stak overflow...Just clicked last option of "add comment"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt with `for-each-group group-adjacent`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::comment()[matches(., '^\s*\[[0-9]+\]\s*')] | self::link[@idref] | self::text()[not(normalize-space())])">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="adjacent"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link[@idref]" mode="adjacent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <dummy cstyle="Superscript">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@idref, '_')"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">,</xsl:if>
            </dummy>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response "Martin Honnen". It's working on only mentioned individual para. I couldn't merge on my original xslt where mentioned other conditions for all nodes. But, your code is guide use to write short-cut.